# Implementation of NFC in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4, nfc

Can NFC(Near field communication) be implemented in iphone? If so, please provide me with links that helps in its coding. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

No, not with existing hardware.

Comment: ok thanks just got a project with it was not able to find any thing that helped thanks Alan

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use NFC on the iPhone? Do you know it has NO hardware support to it?

If you want, you can "create" a NFC Hardware for the iPhone yourself. Take an Arduino Board as a bridge between your iPhone and NFC sensor Hardware. The book "[iOS Sensor Apps with Arduino: Wiring the iPhone and iPad into the Internet of Things](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449308481)" can help you :)